# Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I've been trying to run this script but all I get is this error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 15:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:

constant exception <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
char time timestamp interval date binary national character
nchar
The symbol "IS" was ignored.
```

Here's my script:

```
set serveroutput on

   DECLARE
   cursor depts_cur is select dname from dept;
   depts_cur_rec is depts_cur%type; 

   BEGIN
   loop
     fetch depts_cur into depts_cur_rec;
     exit when depts_cur_rec%notfound;
     dbms_output.put_line('Department: ' || depts_cur_rec);
   end loop;
   close depts_cur;
   END;
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you read the error, it told you exactly what was wrong: Line 3 is `depts_cur_rec is depts_cur%type;`; Column 15 is where the `IS` is.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your depts_cur_rec declaration is wrong, try this (removing the "is"):

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    cursor depts_cur is select dname from dept;
    depts_cur_rec depts_cur%type;
BEGIN
    BEGIN loop 
        fetch depts_cur 
        into depts_cur_rec; 
        exit when depts_cur_rec%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line('Department: ' || depts_cur_rec); 
    end loop;
    close depts_cur;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, when you declare a local variable like `depts_cur_rec`, you don't use the `IS` keyword.  And you want the `depts_cur_rec` to be declared to be a `%ROWTYPE`, not a `%TYPE`.  Once you get past that, your code is going to fail because you aren't opening the cursor before fetching and because you are trying to use the `%NOTFOUND` attribute of the record rather than the cursor.  And finally, your `DBMS_OUTPUT` call needs to reference a particular column from the record

```
DECLARE
   cursor depts_cur is select dname from dept;
   depts_cur_rec depts_cur%rowtype; 
BEGIN
   open depts_cur;
   loop
     fetch depts_cur into depts_cur_rec;
     exit when depts_cur%notfound;
     dbms_output.put_line('Department: ' || depts_cur_rec.dname);
   end loop;
   close depts_cur;
END;
```

It is likely much easier, however, to simply use implicit cursors rather than explicit cursors for this sort of thing.  That way, there is no need to manually specify the `OPEN`, `FETCH`, or `CLOSE`.  There is no need to manually figure out when to exit the loop.  There is no need to manually declare the record type.  You just let Oracle handle that

```
BEGIN
  FOR dept_rec IN (SELECT dname 
                     FROM dept)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Department: ' || dept_rec.dname );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If you want to declare the cursor out-of-line, you can do that with implicit cursors as well

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR depts_cur 
      IS SELECT dname 
           FROM dept;
BEGIN
  FOR dept_rec IN depts_cur
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Department: ' || dept_rec.dname );
  END LOOP;
END;
```